# Codeigniter routing with slug gives me 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, slug

I'm working on a client website which part of it to retrieve news, this is my first codeigniter application and I have followed CI tutorials, slugs and routing.

The problem I'm having is that everything works fine but when it comes to get a record based on slug I get 404. What I did was removed index.php from my URL and tested it, which works fine.

**This is my route.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/singe_news/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
```

**This is my model news_model.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News_model extends CI_Model {


    function get_all(){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM news AS news";  
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();

    }

    //// get a single post

    function get_single($slug = FALSE) {

    if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();


    }


    function news_categories(){

     $sql="SELECT * FROM news_categories";  
     $query=$this->db->query($sql);
     return $query->result();

    }

}
```

**and this is my controller news.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {



    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $data['results']=$this->news_model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('public/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('public/menu');
        $this->load->view('public/news-listing', $data);
        $this->load->view('public/footer', $data);
    }



    public function single_news($slug) {


        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $data['single_news'] = $this->news_model->get_single();

    /// if (empty($data['single_news']))
        /// {
            /// show_404();
            ///}

        $this->load->view('public/header');
        $this->load->view('public/menu');
        $this->load->view('public/single-news', $data);
        $this->load->view('public/footer'); 


    }

}
```

So questions I have:

1- Where does $slug come from? I have a view has

2- Is there anything missing?

URLs need to be

domain.com/news/this-is-a-slug

Many thanks and apologies if this may have been asked in different format with different intention on other posts.

Comment: Change `$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/singe_news/$1';` to `$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/single_news/$1';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Where does $slug come from?*

Your URI looks like this: www.example.com/controller/method/arg1/arg2/arg3 (w/o query string)

*Is there anything missing?*

Well, there is few things you should do:

1. Use autoload (config/autoload.php) to load your most used models, or if this model is not used widely at least load it at class constructor.
2. You are not passing $slug argument to model method, this will not work even if you will fix your routing.

   `$data['single_news'] = $this->news_model->get_single();`
3. Better to show 404 if you can't find a slug, don't refetch all data on fail.

To fix 404 error follow those steps:

1. Check your .htaccess file for errors
2. Check uri_protocol setting in config
3. Try routing like this $route['news/((.+)$)?'] = "news/singe_news/$1"; (this should replace both routes for news)

Comment: Legend, so solution was  1- Correct route, 2- Passed $slug to model, 3- added constructor to class