# URI routing in CodeIgniter causes 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Second EDIT - **Found the Problem, and answered it as well**. 
First Edit - added my Post_model.php file as well for clearer explanation of my code.
I am trying to redirect a Blogs slug to a separate page where I can show the entire  blogs content.

here's an example slug

```
http://localhost/aag/posts/test-one
```

Here's the Posts controller

```
<?php   
class Posts extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
         // Shows a blog listing

    }

    public function view($slug = NULL){
        $data['post'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($slug);
        if(empty($data['post'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['title'] = $data['post']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
}
```

The `posts/view.php` file

```
<h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2>
<small class="post-date">Created on <?php echo $post['created_at']?></small><br>
<div class="post-body">
    <?php echo $post['body']; ?>
</div>
```

the `Post_model.php`

```
class Post_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_posts($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
            $query = $this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => '$slug'));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

`routes.php`

```
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010415/codeigniter-routing-with-slug-gives-me-404

Comment: can you please update your index function in your controller ?

Comment: actually I just found the problem. I am writing the answer as we speak. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so years of writing `mysqli` queries made me do this mistake. In my `Post_model.php` I am getting the data where (DB column field) `slug` should match the `$slug` that gets passed in, but I surrounded the slugs inside single quotes that was causing the error. Here's the working code now.

```
class Post_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_posts($slug = NULL)
    {
        if ($slug === NULL) {
            $query = $this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

TLDR: Don't encapsulate your passed in arguments inside quotes.